# Passing function return value to stored procedure parameter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, parameter-passing, sql-server-2014

Is there a way to pass the return value of a function directly into a stored procedure parameter without first storing in a variable?

For example, given the following stored procedure (which will be on `databaseA`)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MySproc]
   @NAME NVARCHAR(50)
AS
```

I would like to be able to call the following (from `databaseB`)...

```
EXEC [databaseA]..MySproc DB_NAME()
```

This results in the following error:

> Incorrect syntax near ')'.

The following works, but requires two lines...

```
DECLARE @NAME NVARCHAR(50) = DB_NAME()
EXEC [databaseA]..MySproc @NAME
```

I realise on the surface this is not a big issue, but it would really help my situation if I could have it as a single line.  My assumption is this is simply not possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. From [EXECUTE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) the syntax for a stored procedure is the following:

```
Execute a stored procedure or function  
[ { EXEC | EXECUTE } ]  
    {   
      [ @return_status = ]  
      { module_name [ ;number ] | @module_name_var }   
        [ [ @parameter = ] { value   
                           | @variable [ OUTPUT ]   
                           | [ DEFAULT ]   
                           }  
        ]  
      [ ,...n ]  
      [ WITH <execute_option> [ ,...n ] ]  
    }  
[;]
```

Notice that for the parameters the passed value must be a (literal) value, a variable, or the `DEFAULT` keyword. It *cannot* be an expression, which would include something like the simple expression `@Variable + 'string'` *and* scalar functions like `GETDATE()`.

As such you must store the value first in a variable and then pass that variable to the procedure.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation - unfortunate, but expected.  I have now asked a [follow up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68002111)

Comment: Yep, I saw, pretty sure the answer to that is also a "no", @freefaller .

Comment: Yeah, I have that feeling as well... oh well